# Изменение внешнего вида кнопки в Android

Tags: android, switch, customview

Как сделать такой вид переключателей (Boy/girl и F/C) (Т.е прямоугольные с текстом по краям)?
 [image]

Comment: Скорее всего можно модифицировать `switch` для этих целей

Answer (score 0):

Можно например так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Исходники здесь](https://github.com/ceryle/RadioRealButton)

P.S. Реализован как кастомный `RadioButton`